# Java: Json schema generator (for string orJSONObject)

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

Are there any libraries to convert JSON in `String`/`jackson`/`org.JSON.JSONOBJECT`/etc... to a JSON schema?

So far, the only generator I found covert Java classes to JSON schemas. I'm about to write my own converted, but it'd be nice if I didn't have to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

looks like there isn't. I had to write my own generator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is: https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator. It ingests Jacson's `JsonNode` containing the schema definition and can validate JSON data against that schema.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library.

**Convert Java object to JSON:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Staff obj = new Staff();

// 1. Java object to JSON, and save into a file
gson.toJson(obj, new FileWriter("D:\\file.json"));

// 2. Java object to JSON, and assign to a String
String jsonInString = gson.toJson(obj);
```

**Convert JSON to Java object:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// 1. JSON to Java object, read it from a file.
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\file.json"), Staff.class);

// 2. JSON to Java object, read it from a Json String.
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'foo'}";
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Staff.class);

// JSON to JsonElement, convert to String later.
JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\file.json"), JsonElement.class);
String result = gson.toJson(json);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am looking to convert to a schema representation of my json string/object. Not the conversion between types. Thanks for the ack thought!

Comment: @pl0u, You want to generate java classes?